# Enable Node menu automatically

Tags: 7, routes, rules

I have a need to automatically create an Article node type each time a Basic-Page node type is created - I am using Rules successfully to achieve that effect.

My problem is a Menu link also needs to be created for each Article node created. This means the **Provide a menu link** checkbox needs to be automatically enabled in the process of creating each Article node - but it isn't.

[image]

The image above shows the checkbox I'm trying to automatically enable.

When creating an Article node directly, i:e not using Rules to create the new Article node, the box is checked and things work as normal.

**I really need to find a solution which will enable the checkbox as I auto create my node types.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible through the UI. But here is how I would do programmatically:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    $node->menu['enabled'] = 1;
  }
}
```

It would make your "Provide a menu link" checkbox as checked automatically.

You can also set all these values if you need to:

[image]

EDIT: I'm so sorry I forgot the node_save line in the code. Here is the correction:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    $node->menu['enabled'] = 1;
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Djouuuuh but it didn't work. I have tried the exact same segment of code but in hook_node_insert(). I don't know if the difference in hooks makes any difference but neighter solved the problem anyway.

Comment: Please see my update in answer.

Comment: Good morning Djouuuuh. Thank you for the update. Sorry to say I had tried the ndoe_save function but it just results in a loop i:e the Basic-Page node is perpectually "loading". This goes on for a while and I'm yet to see it actually finish :-)

Comment: This is similar to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546839/drupal-modify-node-hook-node-insert-hook-node-insert) and their code works :-(